# how to configure a wix code button return to previous page?

Tags: velo

I need help to configure a button that has the same purpose as any previous button in a browser. I didn't try any concrete solution because my basics in programming are very far and my website is almost finished. Thank you

Comment: Ok so i tried using the add an html element with this code :                            <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>  but it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

You should enable [Wix Code](https://www.wix.com/code/home) in your Wix editor, there you may add interaction and functionality to almost any UI component on screen.

So then you may bind the `onclick` event to your own function handler, in which you may write the code you mentioned in the comments. it will look like this:

```js
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';

export function button1_click(event, $w) {
    const url = wixWindow.referrer;
    wixLocation.to(url);
}
```

More details can be seen here: https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-window.html#referrer